# DBpedia shows no result when it has parentheses

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

DBpedia shows no result when it has parentheses, like this example.

```
PREFIX dbpedia0: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX term: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?item
WHERE
{
?item rdfs:seeAlso <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blockchain_(database)> .
}
```

I confirmed some wiki pages links to "Blockchain_(database)" in their see also section, so it should return some result. But actually it results no result.

I googled and I also tried:

```
?item rdfs:seeAlso dbr:Blockchain_%28database%29 .
```

But didn't work. Can't DBpedia searches parentheses-containing resources?

Comment: I tested your query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ and it seems to return a result.

Comment: **which** DBpedia endpoint do you use? And **how**? Different endpoints do contain different data for reasons ... like live.dbpedia.org/sparql does not work because it simply doesn't contain the data, see http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Bitcoin vs http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bitcoin - open it in the browser and you'll see different facts for `rdfs:seeAlso`

Comment: thanks guys. I was using the live one, didn't notice that. understood the difference.

Comment: Please write up the resolution as an answer, and post it as such, so others may also benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the result might be different depends on the DBpedia endpoint.

- http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql
- http://dbpedia.org/sparql

And you can see the difference manually between the live one and traditional one, if they are indexed on the web server (not only database server).

- live.dbpedia.org/resource/Bitcoin
- dbpedia.org/resource/Bitcoin